# Deleting row in pandas dataframe without effecting index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, ipython, jupyter

I was wondering if there is a way to delete a row from a pandas data frame (I've been using df.drop(df.index[], inplace=True)) that doesn't similarly remove the actual index number? After going through my data frame and removing the rows that need to be removed, I can't loop through the data from anymore. I get KeyError exceptions when ever I hit the index of a removed row. I tried re indexing the dataframe to no effect as well... Pretty new to pandas so I'm not sure what's going on here.

I just need to be able to remove a whole row of data and have the dataframe handle it's own indexing update, or be able to repair and reorder the indexing of my data frame so there are no invalid keys.

Thank you!

Comment: just do df.reset_index(inplace=True) when you need to reset your index after you've removed the rows you don't need.

Comment: https://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_dropping_column_and_rows.html might help

Comment: I tried to reset the index and reindex the whole data frame, no luck :(. Could be I just wasn't using either method correctly. It was almost as if the indexes didn't exist to the point where nothing could even be assigned to them so reindexing didn't do the trick. It was like the reindexing didn't see anything 'wrong'. Thank you for your help, I think you're correct I just don't know if it was me using the methods wrong, or if I'm misunderstanding how dropping an index functions and it's results.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I miss your point then it is pretty obvious that you should get a key error if you try to access something which you removed beforehand. It is possible that you misunderstand how indexing works in a dataframe, so please read the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html). Perhaps you rather want to set the values of "invalid" rows to missing value instead of dropping them?

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your answer :). I assumed that by deleting a row from a data frame via the index method, wouldn't wreck the entire index of the data frame. Things would just be shuffled so you can still loop through the data frame and access things correctly by index. I find it confusing that deleting an index from a data frame not only removes all the data, but seemingly sucks the existence of that index into the abyss. If I had 10 rows and deleted row 9, I assumed row 10 would just become 9. Not that 9 would become a barren wasteland I can't even access anymore to reassign or reindex.

Comment: I think you're right and rather than dropping the indexes to remove rows, I should just reassign them all to nothings. I have to upload these dataframes to google contacts so i'm worried about creating blank contacts I have to go through manually and delete later. Hence the wanting to just drop a row (the whole contact), rather than assign it NaN values. Do you know of another way to simply drop a row like dropping a column?

Answer (score 0):

Below code resets the index, so you can loop through it again.

```
rates.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```